Nextjs hosted in Vercel causing MongoDb collection naming issue
I have a TurboRepo with NextJs web app using MongoDb for database and hosted on Vercel. Here are the versions of the packages:

next: 14.2.4
@typegoose/typegoose: 11.3.0
mongoose: 7.3.1
node: 18.18.2

After deploying the NextJs web app, new collections were generated with weird naming, e.g. "accounts" got named "ys", "stations got named "ds".
Even though the local build and the deployed one are using the same database, it creates a new collection with a single letter naming (plus s, defaulted by MongoDb). screen shot of the collections
I have tried using a different MongDb database connection, different user role, and different database name. I have also tried setting "swcMinify" to false in Next config. As well as running it in both Prod and Review environment.
I am suspecting Vercel is the cause of this, but cannot find a solution.
Has anyone encountered this before or have any idea the cause? Thank you!

I'm encountering this as well, using mongo and typegoose, deployed to aws ec2. I haven't found the solution yet
